# Как сделать нумерацию в html в свойстве data-date=""

Tags: php, html, wordpress, циклы

Есть вот такой код.

Тут в поле data-date="" в кавычки нужна переменная, которая нумерует, то есть с 1 до 20, делает номера вместо пустого места. Например data-date="1" data-date="2" data-date="3" и т.д., уже когда выводит на страницу сайта.

```
    <?php if(get_field('timeline')): ?>
        <ol>

        <?php while(has_sub_field('timeline')): ?>

            <li><a href="#0" data-date=""><?php the_sub_field('year'); ?></a></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ol>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Подсказали что можно через, <?php $inc = 0 <?php echo $inc ?> но я не понимаю что куда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если количество итераций регулируется на уровне цикла `while` функцией `has_sub_field()`, то можно создать счетчик `$i = 0`, который будет увеличиться внутри этого цикла икрементом `$i++`

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php if(get_field('timeline')): ?>
    <ol>

    <?php while(has_sub_field('timeline')): ?>

        <li><a href="#0" data-date="<?= $i++; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('year'); ?></a></li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ol>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! То чно нужно было)